# What was with the giant location titles?

Tags: analysis, marvel-cinematic-universe, captain-america-civil-war

## VIENNA

I really enjoyed *Captain America: Civil War*, but I found myself giggling uncontrollably whenever they'd put up the ENORMOUS location titles.

## LONDON

This seemed a very odd choice. The film did take place in many (IMO unnecessarily many) different cities, so I can see why location titles were used, but why that overblown style? Most of the locations were not particularly significant to the story, they could have said...

## CHEBOYGAN

...and it would have made as much story impact. It seems more appropriate to place them in the lower-third of the screen as is traditional.

Why did the director choose this style? Is it a trademark of the director? Or maybe some sort of homage to another movie, maybe a spy movie, or comic book? It reminded me somewhat of the "TUESDAY" title cards from *The Shining*, but that's so out of place in this movie.

## MOOSE FACTORY

What? It's a real place, look it up.

Comment: Agreed. They were intrusive and annoying.

Comment: Maybe too many people (or a rich executive) complained that they missed the smaller ones before?

Comment: Probably an hommage to old movies, and maybe in the Civil War comics too, but also it highlights that's it's all the governments (in fact 117 countries) involved, and they are not only the Avengers for the USA (in contradiction to Captain America which hold it in its name America), but for the whole world.

Comment: I think it's mostly a design fashion thing. There's been a trend for these huge type, block-capitals city names in pale text superimposed over a city scene, especially on t-shirts ([here's an example](https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/49/d8/5b/49d85bd3c335f8fd06b329eab82c9a9a.jpg), and [another](https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/82/93/3b/82933bb9edef54c980ec0f628c266e4f.jpg), and [another](https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/ef/58/94/ef58947cdc6690f781a5f64a63654a3e.jpg)), also in advertising & web design. I guess the designer just used a recent/current trend.

Answer (score 2):

The huge location titles were used because Jeff Ford (the editor of all the Cap movies and the Avengers movies) felt that people don't really register tiny location titles at the bottom of the screen.

They wanted people to realize, more than where the scene was, that the title markers meant a scene change and to prepare for something different.

Even though the movie is called [Civil War](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Captain_America:_Civil_War), the big names are supposed to give us a feeling that it's a **global** crisis, and all nations are affected by the actions of superheroes.

> Avengers that the United Nations (UN) is preparing to pass the Sokovia Accords, which will establish a UN panel to oversee and control the team.

It's not only the USA, all countries in the United Nations(UN) are involved and signed the Sokovia Accords.

Also, the **big** names emphasize the world tension going on in the movie a lot more than **small** names.

This video poses a theory linking it to the introduction of Spiderman, who is famously from Queens:

Comment: do you have a source on that Jeff Ford quote?

Comment: Please don't add malicious links to answers, I just got a heap of dodgy downloaders, spam tabs and similar from that "4chandata" link

Comment: @user568458 Well, I didnt got anything so I thought it was ok...Sorry about that...

Answer (score -3):

## Unfortunately,

I think this just comes down to a stylistic choice on either the Director or Editor's part.

## The effect

is quite jarring but it does make it quite obvious that *ok now we are making it very obvious to you that the action has shifted to a new location* to help get the global feeling of the situation across.